# Why can a = b imply 2 = 1?

Tags: fake-proofs

$$ a = b $$
$$ a^2 = ab $$
$$ a^2 - b^2 = ab - b^2 $$
$$ (a+b)(a - b) = b(a - b) $$
$$ a + b = b $$
$$ 2b = b $$
$$ 2 = 1 $$

Does the self-reference to the original formula make this path of argument invalid? I am confused as to what's going on here.

Would this be a better continuation from $a + b = b$:

$$ a + b = b \implies a = 0 \implies b = 0$$

Comment: cant divide by $a-b$ if $a=b$

Comment: Just about all of these "troll proofs" have a disguised division by zero in one of the steps.

Comment: Does exist some sort of "normal" form I have to reduce the formula to before I can do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement $$\mbox{If $xy=xz$, then $y=z$}$$ is **false**: for example, $0\cdot 1=0\cdot 2$ but $1\not=2$. What *is* true is that $$\mbox{If $xy=xz$, then $y=z$ or $x=0$.}$$ So when you go from $$(a+b)(a−b)=b(a−b)$$ to $$(a+b)=b,$$ that's not justified; instead, from $$(a+b)(a-b)=b(a-b)$$ all you can conclude is *either* $(a+b)=b$, or $(a-b)=0$. And indeed, $(a-b)=0$.

Comment: The thing I have always found odd about this particular fake proof is that even *after* that faulty step, it fails to arrive at a contradictory state. It only arrives at a state where $a + b = b$, implying $a = b = 0$, and then has to divide by $0$ *again* to arrive at the contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

You're dividing by zero in the fourth line because $a=b$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$a=b\implies a-b=0$$

So the third step is not allowed since you can't divide by zero.