# Why if $a =b$ then $a = 0$ is not a correct statement

Tags: fake-proofs

Bogus Claim: If $a$ and $b$ are two equal real numbers, then $a = 0$

$a = b$

$a^2 = ab$

$a^2 - b^2 = ab - b^2$

$(a-b)(a+b) = (a-b)b$

$a + b = b$

$a = 0$

I found this in my proof handouts, and correct me if I'm wrong,but is it wrong because after line 4 we divide both sides by $(a - b)$ which would be $0$ if $a = b$ ?

Comment: This is essentially the same as [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2026631/why-can-a-b-imply-2-1/2026644#2026644). The conclusion is different ($1=2$ instead of $a=0$) but the argument and flaw are the same.

Comment: Question :What wrong most of the people do in such fake proofs?? Answer :They divide 0 by 0.

Comment: @THELONEWOLF.: Do you actually have a proof of that??? I would tend to guess that even if you do somehow, it is most certainly faked (and most certainly because you've based it on insufficient statistics rather than dividing $0$ by $0$).

Comment: @barakmanos, honestly speaking, what you are saying is going over my head. Do you want me to prove that in mathematics, dividing 0 by 0 is illegal ??

Comment: @THELONEWOLF.: No, I asked if you have a proof for the fact that you stated.

Comment: For what ?? The answer: (They divide 0 by 0)??

Comment: @THELONEWOLF.: Do you actually have a proof of your claim that most of the people who write such faked proofs actually divide $0$ by $0$?

Comment: To close this discussion , I would say I have no proof. :) :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You take the equation $(a-b)(a+b)=(a-b)b$
2. You divide each side by $(a-b)$
3. You get the equation $a + b = b$

But $a=b\implies(a-b)=0$, which means that step #2 is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

You are dividing the 4th line by $a-b$, which is zero by your assumption

Comment: Thank you,that's what i wanted to know.